# 32 bit application won't run on some Win7 64 bit machines

Tags: visual-c++

Our 32 bit macro utility will not run on some random Win 7 64 bit machines. Here's the error:

```
HooksApi.cpp : 73 - c203 - void __thiscall HooksApi::Initialize(const wchar_t *)
-> The system could not find the environment option that was entered.

HooksApi.cpp : 69 - void __thiscall HooksApi::Initialize(const wchar_t *)
MacroEngine.cpp : 276 - void __thiscall MacroEngine::Initialize(const wchar_t *,struct HWND__ *)AIMTools.cpp : 838 - int __thiscall CAIMToolsApp::InitInstance(void)


HooksApi.cpp : 175 - int __thiscall HooksApi::UninstallHooks(void)
HooksApi.cpp : 167 - int __thiscall HooksApi::UninstallHooks(void)
MacroEngine.cpp : 449 - void __thiscall MacroEngine::Uninitialize(void)
AIMTools.cpp : 1381 - int __thiscall CAIMToolsApp::ExitInstance(void)
```

Where would be the first place the author of the program should look to resolve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Well, what is "HooksApi" and what does it do? That's where I'd start. (It may also be beneficial to track down *what* differs between the working and non-working systems.)

Comment: To know what is going on, your question needs more context, and more importantly some source code. The error message looks like it comes from the method `HooksApi::Initialize`, so without seeing what that does, you'll probably have trouble finding the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the error you're seeing is being generated by the `HooksApi::Initialize()` method, so without seeing the code it's impossible to tell what's going on.

From the error message tho', I would guess that an environment variable, or some other environment setting is being tested, and is not being found.

The "author of the program" should look at `HooksApi::Initialize()` and to see what causes that error to be generated.